# Palette window issue(in eclipse)

Tags: java

I have downloaded a windows builder in eclipse and my window palette is not working, I cannot use the components present in it. From the image you can see that the window palette is not showing correctly, the close,max, and min button is not there.

[as you can see the palette window is not showing correctly as it has no max, min, close option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06FLX.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when I dragged and dropped the jlabel component to palette window, I still can dragged and dropped it but I can't write or put any labels on it. It says new label and when I right clicked on it the cursor didn't even appear and the 'new  label' is still on display.

Comment: I have reuploaded the photo please check if you can see it.